# python setattr function does not set

Tags: python, class, python-module, getattr, setattr

I have a module and two classes which are called A and B. I would like to record some functions from `duvisiopy.model_functions` module into class B by using class A then return B. As you can see the output1, they are recorded and they are runnable.

```
#duvisiopy.model_functions

def compile(self,
            loss_function,
            optimizer):
    self.loss_function = loss_function
    self.optimizer = optimizer
```

```
import types
import duvisiopy.model_functions


class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = "b"

class A():

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
    def __new__(self, cls):
        for attr_name in dir(duvisiopy.model_functions):

            if attr_name not in dir(cls) and not attr_name.startswith("_"):

                attr = getattr(duvisiopy.model_functions, attr_name)
                if not isinstance(attr, types.ModuleType):

                    attr = attr.__get__(duvisiopy.model_functions,
                                        duvisiopy.model_functions.__class__)
                    print(attr_name)

                    setattr(cls, attr_name, attr)
        return cls



b = B()

a = A(b)
a.compile("test1","test2")

for i in dir(a):

    if not a.starsith("_"):
        print(i)
```

output1 is

```
compile
evaluate
fit
progressbar
```

However, If I try to reach `a.optimizer`, it throws error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#54>", line 1, in <module>
    a.optimizer
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'optimizer'
```

What is the problem ?

**UPDATE 1**

if I set compile function to return self

```
#duvisiopy.model_functions

def compile(self,
            loss_function,
            optimizer):
    self.loss_function = loss_function
    self.optimizer = optimizer

    return self
```

```
c = a.compile("test1","test2")
```

it prints

```
'absolute_path\\duvisiopy\\model_functions.py'
```

and if I try to reach `optimizer` by `c`, it prints,

```
print(c.optimizer) #--> 'test2'
```

Comment: where is defined `optimizer`? Your output is partial, are missing all the prints from the decoration with `__new__`

Comment: @cards optimizer is defined in the first code block. You can see it is in compile function. I think outputs belongs to __new__ are not so important because it set the functions.

Comment: maybe `setattr(type(cls), ...)` should be enough

Comment: @cards Unfortunately does not work, I added an update to the question. I think self in compile returns module - `duvisiopy.model_functions`- not class B.